# Is it Possible to create a AD User with c# and fill his phonenumber?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to fill the Telephone number with a winform in C#?
[AD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onWnQ.png)

At the moment I added

```
  using System.DirectoryServices;
  using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

to my code, but dont find a solution for my problem.

Thank you mery much for your help!

I tried my code to create the user looks like this:

```
newUser.SamAccountName = username;
   newUser.GivenName = firstName;
   newUser.Surname = lastName;
   newUser.SetPassword(password);
   newUser.Enabled = true;
   newUser.Description = OutputMail.Text; 
   newUser.telephone = phoneNumber; 
   newUser.Save();
```

every attribute is working fine except the telephonenumber.

Comment: it's probably `VoiceTelephoneNumber` not "`telephone`" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.voicetelephonenumber?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-directoryservices-accountmanagement-userprincipal-voicetelephonenumber

Answer (score 0):

The correct property for telephone number is `VoiceTelephoneNumber`. The property `telephone` you entered is not a valid property.

So your code would be:

```cs
newUser.SamAccountName = username;
newUser.GivenName = firstName;
newUser.Surname = lastName;
newUser.SetPassword(password);
newUser.Enabled = true;
newUser.Description = OutputMail.Text;
newUser.VoiceTelephoneNumber = phoneNumber;
newUser.Save();
```

More examples are available on the [Microsofts Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb384369(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) page.